# How to accelerate nested loop in Python

Tags: python, performance, nested-loops

I need to find the nearest ATM to each city zone 100*100 meters. So I have a DF with ATMs (ID, lon, lat): atms_needed and a DF with the coordinates of zones' centers. So I created Point objects from ATMs and zones' centers:

```
zones_msk_spb["left_bottom"] = [lonlat(x,y) for x,y in zip(zones_msk_spb.ldx, zones_msk_spb.ldy)]

zones_msk_spb["top_right"] = [lonlat(x,y) for x,y in zip(zones_msk_spb.rtx, zones_msk_spb.rty)]

zones_msk_spb["center"] = zones_msk_spb.apply(lambda x: midpoint(x.left_bottom, x.top_right), axis=1)

atms_needed["atm_point"] = [lonlat(x,y) for x,y in zip(atms_needed.lon, atms_needed.lat)]
```

And then do the following:

```
# Get Matrix of distances Zones-ATMs

zones_atms_matrix = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in atms_needed.iterrows():

      zones_atms_matrix[index] = [distance(zone_center, row.atm_point).km

                                                                for zone_center in zones_msk_spb.center]
```

Unfortunately it's too slow when data is pretty big. Does anyone know how to rewrite that loop? (After getting the matrix I simply choose min in each row)
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for showing your code. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).